# dart: changing list[i] changes list[i-1] too

Tags: dart

I have a `List` of the type `Model`. when I loop all its elements and loop the next one except for the last one, then change the last one manually, the one before changes.

here is a little code to reproduce the problem ([also you can run it directly in `dartpad` from here](https://dartpad.dev/c5e079859142ca9114b5d19d63e94104?null_safety=true))

```
void main() {
  List<Model> s = [];
  for (int i = 0; i < 5; i++) {
    s.add(Model(i));
  }
  for (int i = 0; i < s.length - 1; i++) {
    s[i] = s[i + 1];
  }
  print(s);
  s[s.length-1].x = 100;
  print(s);
}

class Model {
  int x;
  Model(this.x);
  @override
  String toString() => 'x: ' + this.x.toString();
}
```

notice that this problem does not happen when you comment out the for loop or the manual change, or instead of changing the last one's property, you reassign a new value to it, like `s[s.length - 1] = Model(100);`. seems like `dart` for some reason is re-running the loop.

Comment: What is `s[i] = s[i + 1];` intended to do?  What it actually ends up doing is making the second-to-last element refer to the same object as the last element, so mutating that object will show a visible change to both elements.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

When you run the second `for` loop, you assign the `i + 1`th `Model` to the `i`th position in the list:

```dart
// initialise list
for (int i = 0; i < s.length; i++) {
  s[i] = s[i + 1]
}
```

If you unwrap the loop, it looks roughly like this:

```dart
s[0] = s[1];
s[1] = s[2];
s[2] = s[3];
s[3] = s[4];
```

Notice that this leaves `s[4]` unchanged, but also assigns it to `s[3]`.

In Dart, variables contain references to objects. This means that when your list runs `s[3] = s[4];`, both `s[3]` and `s[4]` point to the same object.

Now, if you modify `s[4]` you, are actually modifying *the objects that `s[4]` refers to*, which happens to also be the object that `s[3]` refers to, so they both appear to change in your list.

Comment: Well, thx for the answer. so as I understand is it a pointer situation? how can I copy the value of `s[4]` and not its place in memory? `s[3].x = s[4].x;` is doing the trick, but I don't see that scaling, like that would not work in the models that have 10 properities.

Comment: @Adnan You would need to add a method to `Model` to copy its properties from another instance.

Comment: well, but that solution too, requires manual work. `Model mod = s[i+1]; s[i] = mod;` also seems to not do the trick.

Comment: Dart does not natively let you do a deep copy of the state of an object. If you want this, have a look at a package called `built_value`, which allows you to define types that can be easily copied (it does a lot more than that though!) https://pub.dev/packages/built_value